# No route matches {:controller=>"generators", :action=>"new"} missing required keys: [:user_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get this code work but i do not know how should i fix it. the error i got is

```
No route matches {:controller=>"generators", :action=>"new"} missing required keys: [:user_id]
```

**USER**

```
 has_many :generators
      has_many :results, :through=>:generators
```

**GENERATOR**

```
has_one :result , :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :user
```

**RESULT**

```
belongs_to :generator
   belongs_to :user, :through=>:generators
```

This is my home page with :

```
 <%= link_to 'HOME', root_path, id:'home' %>
                     <%= link_to 'GENERATE RAPD PRIMER',new_user_generator_path, id:'new' %></li>
                     <%= link_to 'VIEW RESULT HISTORY', user_generators_path,id:'view'%></li>
```

my **rake routes** are :

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
               signout GET    /signout(.:format)                            sessions#destroy
                  root GET    /                                             welcome#index
                       GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)            sessions#create
auth_identity_callback POST   /auth/identity/callback(.:format)             sessions#create
       user_generators GET    /users/:user_id/generators(.:format)          generators#index
                       POST   /users/:user_id/generators(.:format)          generators#create
    new_user_generator GET    /users/:user_id/generators/new(.:format)      generators#new
   edit_user_generator GET    /users/:user_id/generators/:id/edit(.:format) generators#edit
        user_generator GET    /users/:user_id/generators/:id(.:format)      generators#show
                       PATCH  /users/:user_id/generators/:id(.:format)      generators#update
                       PUT    /users/:user_id/generators/:id(.:format)      generators#update
                       DELETE /users/:user_id/generators/:id(.:format)      generators#destroy
          user_results GET    /users/:user_id/results(.:format)             results#index
                       POST   /users/:user_id/results(.:format)             results#create
       new_user_result GET    /users/:user_id/results/new(.:format)         results#new
      edit_user_result GET    /users/:user_id/results/:id/edit(.:format)    results#edit
           user_result GET    /users/:user_id/results/:id(.:format)         results#show
                       PATCH  /users/:user_id/results/:id(.:format)         results#update
                       PUT    /users/:user_id/results/:id(.:format)         results#update
                       DELETE /users/:user_id/results/:id(.:format)         results#destroy
                 users GET    /users(.:format)                              users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)                              users#create
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                          users#new
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                     users#edit
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#show
                       PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                          users#destroy
            identities GET    /identities(.:format)                         identities#index
                       POST   /identities(.:format)                         iden
          new_identity GET    /identities/new(.:format)                     iden
         edit_identity GET    /identities/:id/edit(.:format)                iden
              identity GET    /identities/:id(.:format)                     iden
                       PATCH  /identities/:id(.:format)                     iden
                       PUT    /identities/:id(.:format)                     iden
                       DELETE /identities/:id(.:format)                     iden
```

whenever some1 clicks GENERATE RAPD PRIMER, he/she has to be login first before can use that. So in this error how can i fix them ?

Answer (score 1):

in your generators controller, set @user to current user

```
@user = current_user 
#handle this however you want - define the user that is on the page
```

then in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'GENERATE RAPD PRIMER', new_user_generator_path(id:@user.id) %>
```

Comment: hi dax where should i place that @user = current_user ? under generator controller new / create ? my flow is alittle weird. from thaterror it gives , it is telling me that there's no user id that's why it is appearing that error. But that is suppose to be the homepage. If user is login only they can click generate new RAPD primer else they will just see the word there

Comment: home is from welcome controller (root) . generator controller will only successful load if user is login. But in my homepage ( welcome controller ) which is ths page i'm trying to load, gives me error bcoz of the generate nwe primer link_to

Comment: ah, i see - the problem is that there should be no :id call in that route if you're using it to generate new users.  please put your 'routes.rb' into your post - the problem is there, but luckily it should be easy to fix :)

Comment: erm in order to generate, user has to be login. After login, then only user can click that. And the results will be save to user's record

Comment: ...this link is to create a new user...but the user needs to be logged in before they can create themselves...?  is this some new-fangled goose-in-a-bottle app?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42588/discussion-between-bc2-and-dax)

Answer (score 1):

**generators_controller**

```
@user = current_user
```

**in the view**

```
<%= link_to 'GENERATE RAPD PRIMER',new_user_generator_path(@user), id:'new' %></li>
<%= link_to 'VIEW RESULT HISTORY', user_generators_path(@user),id:'view'%></li>
```